# Regex to remove HTML-head-tag

Tags: iphone, regex, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios

how can I remove, with NSRegularExpression, the entire head-tag in a HTML file. Can some one give me a regex?

Thanks in advance,
Ph99Ph

Comment: @Don: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73133/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is none! **HTML is a type-2 language** and thus **not parsable with a regular expression** (type-3).

**See [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#The_hierarchy) in case of doubt.**

Lots of people use regex for parsing/editing HTML. This works quite well in simple cases but is utterly error prone.

This being said: You should have fairly reliable results with this regex:

```
<head>.+?</head>
```

This requires "." to also match line breaks. If it doesn't, then use this:

```
<head>(?:.|\n|\r)+?</head>
```

**Again: This is error prone, don't do it.**

What **you should use** is an **XML parser** such as `NSXMLParser`.

Comment: To be fair, this is a common misconception endorsed in particular by the waste amount of ill informed online articles on parsing/validating/editing html with regex. I can only whole-heartedly recommend to read the wiki article that I liked to in my answer. Understanding language complexity is a big thing. Basically omnipresent in computer science/programming. Well worth the read.

Comment: To also match line breaks a modifier can be used: /<head>.*<\/head>/s

Comment: @FelixEve: `NSRegularExpression` isn't like **PHP/PERL/…** where **regex** are defined like `/pattern/flags`/`/pattern/template/flags`. Instead you'd have to provide the `NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators` bitmask option to it.

Comment: One comment, should not the slash in the closing tag be scaped? `<head>(?:.|\n|\r)+?<\/head>`

Comment: @aUXcoder: That depends on whether the programming language you're using uses `/…/` literals for regex (in which case you'd be right of course).

Answer (score 3):

Please see the accepted answer at [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).  Or any version of this exact same question posted each day since the beginning of Stack Overflow.

In short, you cannot reliably parse HTML with Regular Expressions. RegEx is simply not advanced enough because of the complexities of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this :

```
result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
         @"<( )*head([^>])*>", "<head>",
         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
         @"(<( )*(/)( )*head( )*>)", "</head>",
         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);                
result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
         "(<head>).*(</head>)", " ",
         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```